# How do I allow both kg and lbs units for a field

Tags: entities

I want the user to be able to submit weight as either kg or lbs and do any necessary conversion on the fly. I took a look at [Unit Conversion Formatters](https://drupal.org/project/unit_conversion_formatters) but it seems that this is designed to convert for display only (not for storage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two fields, one for number, second for unit. Optionally put them in a [field  collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Then, add [Computed field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) that will use both values for computation and store the result the way you need it. For best flexibility, you might want to create two of them, ie `field_real_kg` and `field_real_lbs`.

> computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields